# The Latin word “Have” rather than “Ave” as a translation of the Greek word Χαῖρε?

Tags: greek, christianity, orthography, vulgata, spelling

According to BlueLetterBible, the Latin Vulgate translation of Matthew 26:49 states,

[image: BlueLetterBible, Matt. 26:49, Vulgate]

The Greek text from the Textus Receptus states,

> <sup>ΜΘʹ</sup> καὶ εὐθέως προσελθὼν τῷ Ἰησοῦ εἶπεν **Χαῖρε** ῥαββί καὶ κατεφίλησεν αὐτόν <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

I assumed the Latin translation of *Χαῖρε* to be *Ave*, but what is *Have*? Is that a typo?

Comment: My Colunga-Turrado edition of the *Vulgata Clementina* has "Ave" here.

Comment: Possibly assimilation to a 'hard H' pronunciation of *Haire* / Χαῖρε.

Comment: See also: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15836/was-av%C4%93-truly-pronounced-with-an-unspelled-h

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an alternate form of *[ave](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daveo2)*; the L&S entry gives a couple of examples.

Presumably this form arose through [hypercorrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection): since *h* was generally not pronounced in popular speech, confusion easily arose about which words did and did not contain it. Catullus [makes fun of a certain Arrius](http://www.vroma.org/~hwalker/VRomaCatullus/084.html) who inserted *h*'s where they weren't needed.

Comment: I prefer to call him *Harrius*.

Comment: Et vīvēbat in aedibus Gestātiōnis Ligustrōrum numerō quattuor signātis.

Answer (score 15):

There is a longstanding view that the interjection *ave* is not the imperative of the verb *aveo* “to long for”, but is a loan from Punic *ḥawe* (tentative vocalisation), the imperative of the Semitic verb ḥ-w-h “to live”. The first attestations are in Plautus, who also uses the plural *havo* (=Punic *ḥawū*) three times in his *Poenulus*. If this is true, then *have* would actually be the etymologically correct spelling.

See the discussion in Walde, *Lat. Etym. Wb.*, who comes out in favour of this analysis. By contrast, de Vaan, *Etym. dict. of Latin* does not even mention it as a possibility.

Comment: De Vaan (unfortunately) excludes loanwords completely, so his lack of an entry for *ave* may actually mean he accepts the Phoenician etymology. The connection with the verb meaning "long for" does seem semantically difficult; L&S list the words separately. Weiss lists *ave* as a Phoenician loanword, without discussion.

Answer (score 2):

'Have' is a variation albeit not popular, of 'ave'. Please be advised. It can be seen in some inscriptions. Check out the wiki page of ave, with the image if it is still there.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jondel! Can you edit your answer to add a link, and perhaps the image itself (with proper attribution)?