# Is the ancient word Greek πῐ́θηκος / píthēkos ("monkey") attested with the meaning "dwarf" more than once?

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek, history, vulgar-latin, romance-languages

I am interested in the obscure etymology of popular Romanian word "[*pitic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pitic)" (n.m. "dwarf", adj. "of small stature").

It might have a connection with the Latin line that led to the French "*petit*" or Italian "*piccolo*" (small), as in Romanian there is also "*pici*"=small boy, maybe related to Albanian *picërr* adj. "tiny, small", *picërrak* "small/frail kid", *picë* "small girl", within a larger semantic area.

But in modern Greek there is the much more similar word [*πίθηκος* (píthikos)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%AF%CE%B8%CE%B7%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%82#Greek), meaning  *ape, monkey* and also *an uncivilized person*.

The meaning seems different but that comes from the ancient *πίθηκος - píthēkos* - for which [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%AF%CE%B8%CE%B7%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%82#Noun) also gives the meaning "dwarf", and I think that is the base for the suggestion the ancient Greek word for "monkey" is related to the Romanian term.

That brings more uncertainty and I would like to see if the Greek word could be ruled out or confirmed as *origin* for the Romanian.

The "dwarf" sense of the Greek word is based on  [Henry George Liddell, Robert Scott, *A Greek-English Lexicon* (1940)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=pi/qhkos), which says: *dwarf, Suid.*, which I guess links to [Suda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suda) lexicon.

[There](https://lexicon.katabiblon.com/suda/index.php?letter=p), píthēkos [*"what some call a short little man"*](https://www.cs.uky.edu/%7Eraphael/sol/sol-cgi-bin/search.cgi?login=guest&searchstr=pi,1578&field=adlerhw_gr) is linked to [Πίθηξ](https://www.cs.uky.edu/%7Eraphael/sol/sol-cgi-bin/search.cgi?login=guest&searchstr=pi,1582&field=adlerhw_gr), *"Used in the sense of "dwarf" by Procopius, Gothic War 4.24"*.

That is [Procopius of Caesarea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procopius) of the 6th century, who comes rather late and might have used common terms of the larger Byzantine and Balkan linguistic area (north of the [Jireček Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jire%C4%8Dek_Line)), in which case the *Greek* "dwarf" meaning might be a loan from that common [Albanian-Romanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian%E2%80%93Romanian_linguistic_relationship) base (rather than the source of the Romanian term): unless that meaning is really anciently Greek and was somehow attested earlier or at least in some other (even *later*!) cases.

*Etymological Dictionary of Greek* by Robert Steven Paul Beeke & Lucien van Beek doesn't mention the meaning "small/dwarf" in the article on *píthēkos*,  no more than  *Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue grecque* by Boisacq,

[image]

[image]

just the former mentions a detail relative to that semantic area:

> Isolated is pithon/pithonos, [m.] 'small monkey' (Pi., Babr.),
> probably a hypocoristic.

That form is related to Pindarus, which is old enough, but seemingly just a diminutive of "monkey".

The semantic connection between "(small) monkey" and "small man, dwarf" seems probable (maybe large monkeys were hard to see in the past and all of them were imagined small) but if that is so the "dwarf" meaning of *pithekos* should be more common in classic and Byzantine Greek than a single occurrence in Procopius' book.

Was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I have read in order to answer a different question (namely [Is the word "pitikkus" (meaning small) attested in Vulgar (or other) Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/18923/3284)) I have come to the conclusion that no matter the answer to this one, it has become a bit otiose: that term (even if attested in other sources than the occurence in Procopius) ***is not a Greek word***.

The fact that the Greek word meaning "monkey" has been used once (and not much more than that) with the meaning "dwarf" was most probably based on a temporary contamination that is not recorded in the dictionaries.

---

Both questions are related to the same type of Wiktionary page. Looking more into it I had the occasion to reevaluate my trust in such internet sources. Often information is confusing, the links are wrong.

The bad page is [this, on *pitic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pitic):

> Unknown. Possibly from piti (“to hide”). Or related to Greek πίθηκος
> (píthikos, “monkey”), cf. Proto-Slavic *pitikъ. See also Vulgar Latin
> *pitikkus (“small”). Compare Sardinian pitticcu (“small”) and Basque pitika (“kid”).

Almost everything is wrong there:

- "pitic" means dwarf, small, and imagining it comes from a verb "to hide" (to make oneself small) may seem to make sense. But the link sends to nothing related to Romanian and is anyway misleading: Romanian [dictionaries](https://dexonline.ro/definitie/PITI/definitii) either circularly reconstruct the verb "a piti" from the word "pitic" or assign to it an unknown origin.
- the Greek and the Slavic connections are both misleading: that Old-Slavic term has the same form and meaning as the Greek one and is obviously *based on it* (as confirmed by Franz Miklosich - *Etymologisches Wörterbuch der slavischen Sprachen* 1886, p. 248) - which led me to the question above. It is on the other hand incredible for a word absent in all modern Slavic languages to be present in Romanian *with a different meaning* and  for that Romanian word to share both meaning and morphology with many Neolatin words without being related to them etymologically.
- as for the rest of the information it's even worse: the first two links lead to yet absent pages, the Basque one leads to a Swahili word: moreover, there is no *pitikkus* in reconstructed Latin, although it may be a "pitticus".

The real situation is this:

Lat. *pitinnus* and *pitulus* are doublets of *pisinnus*, meaning small, little boy or little girl (*Dictionnaire etymologique de la langue latine* Meillet-Ernout, first ed. 1935, 2001, p 510). *Dictionnaire latin - francais by Gaffiot* 1936 says *marmot, bambin*. *Oxford Latin Dictionary* 1968 says: *pisinnus* -a -urn, a. [perh. infantile wd.]
Tiny, little; (masc. as sb.) a little child.

These are Vulgar Latin words, absent in a dictionary like *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the Other Italic Langs by M. de Vaan* Brill 2008. In *Vulgar Latin* 2000, by Herman, Jâozsef, page 101, we can read that

> "the word for “small,” *paruus*, was replaced everywhere by words
> that seem really to come from the nursery, such as *pitinnus*,
> *pisinnus*, *putillus*(teeny)"

There is in Sardinian *pithinnu* (we find in Corominas, J. & Pascual, J.A, *Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico*, Editorial Gredos, Madrid, 1987, p. 484, under PEQUEÑO)  if not even *piticu*, a Milanese *pitin*, along with the French *petit*.

On the other hand: In Calabrese there is *picca* "small piece," in Romanian *pici* (small boy) and *pic* ("a drop, a small piece"), in Italian *piccolo* and *piccino*, in Sardinian *piccinu, picciocu*, all meaning "small".

These words led to (Vulgar) Latin reconstructions;

*pittus*  > *pittitus*, *pittinus*, *pitticus*

*piccus* > *piccinus*, *piccoccus*, *picculus*

(The above can be read at page 33 of *The Reduplication of Consonants in Vulgar Latin* by Albert J. Carnoy,  Modern Philology , Jul., 1917, Vol. 15, No. 3 (Jul., 1917), pp. 159-180, accessible online at [this link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/432937#metadata_info_tab_contents).)

One can see that the Latin words of the form `p-t-*` and `p-s-*` have resulted in:

- a `p-c-*` form in Italian area (*piccino*, *piccolo*, Sardinian *piccinu, picciocu*), Iberic area (Spanish *pequeño*; *pequeno* in Portuguese), Albanian (derivatives of *picë*) and Romanian (*pici*, small boy, "pic", a bit, a drop)

and

- a `p-t-*` form in French (*petit* and related), Italian area (Milanese: *pitinu*, Sardinian: *pithinnu*, *piticu*) and Romanian (*pitic*)

And the two forms are not specific to Western or Eastern Romance nor otherwise geographically separated:

[image]

I think this is overwhelming proof that the origin of the Romanian word *pitic* cannot be found outside the area of Romance languages.

The same proof pleads heavily in favor of the idea that the use of *pithekos* with the meaning "small" or "dwarf" - even if that has happened more than once - cannot be explained except by a confusion with (contamination by) a similar-sounding word of late-Latin.

An article that I read after posting this answer shows that what I argue here is largely accepted in the recent research on the matter: Przemysław Dębowiak, *“Contribution à l’étymologie des adjectifs romans signifiant ‘petit’* - online [here](https://www.academia.edu/33410437/Contribution_%C3%A0_l_%C3%A9tymologie_des_adjectifs_romans_signifiant_petit_). That also shows that some Wictionary pages are much better than the one discussed above: the scholarly article is linked as source of the page for [*puțin*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pu%C8%9Bin#Etymology) meaning "little" (quantitative: French *peu*, Ital. *poco*). The article of the Polish researcher includes many other related words, making a much more competent and developed argument in favor of what I have said.

---

**Was there a Greek word somehow related to the Latin family mentioned above?** --
Surely not, because nothing in relation to the Greek linguistic area appears in the discussion of these words (excepting that dubious Slavic-Greek connection for my Romanian word: which pleads against the quality of some internet sources as well as against many outdated etymologies given in Romanian academic (but non-etymological) dictionaries, because an authoritative and complete etymological dictionary of Romanian has not yet been published.)

**Is there to be attested another use of the Greek word *pithekos* with the meaning "dwarf"?**
-- Most probably not: doubts could be raised about that single occurrence in Procopius sooner than in favor of a second occurrence. (Not to mention simply that were a such occurrence to exist it would not have been absent in the dictionary that mentioned the first.)