# Is the word "pitikkus" (meaning small) attested in Vulgar (or other) Latin?

Tags: etymology, history, vulgar-latin, romance-languages

Being interested in the obscure etymology of popular Romanian word "[pitic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pitic)" (n.m. "dwarf", adj. "of small stature") I have oddly concentrated only on a possible Greek-Slavic connection and have posted this question:  [Is the ancient word Greek πῐ́θηκος / píthēkos ("monkey") attested with the meaning "dwarf" more than once?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/18890/3284), while omitting maybe the most important part of that Wictionary page which links to **Vulgar Latin *pitikkus* (“small”)**, Sardinian *pitticcu* (“small”) and Basque *pitika* (“kid”). (See the links at the page linked above, I am not adding the three links here directly because they are not useful: the first two lead to yet absent pages, the Basque one leads to a Swahili word.)

So, my question is obvious and plain: ***is there an attestation in Vulgar Latin (or in Latin for that matter) of a word like *pittikus*?***

---

In Corominas, J. & Pascual, J.A, *Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico*, Editorial Gredos, Madrid, 1987, the Castilian *pequeño* is considered an expressive form but related to a lot of other Romance words like French *petit*, Italian *piccolo, piccino*, Sardinian *pithinnu*, Gascon *pounnin*, but also the *Vulgar* Latin *pitinnus*.

[image]

Could it be that Wiktionary is simply misspelling the Latin and Sardinian words?

Corominas notes that the Iberian forms are a transformation of the Latin form with an internal consonant like in Italian *piccolo*, which means that within the structure `p + t + n` the  internal consonant `t/th` is replaced by `c/q/k`. That is not the case in Sardinian, which keeps the Latin consonants `p + t/th + n`.

The symmetrical variation where the *other* internal consonant is replaced by `c`, thus providing the formula for the Romanian word *pitic*, `p + t`, is present in the French *petit*.

It is worth noticing that Romanian  has a `p + c` variant too, "*pici*"=small boy, maybe related to Albanian *picërr* adj. "tiny, small", *picërrak* "small/frail kid", *picë* "small girl" as well as the Italian and other forms. That all this family or words are probably based on an expressive (onomatopoetic) form is probably reflected in Romanian by the expression *pic-pic* which imitates the falling of water drops, while *un pic* means "a bit", "very small quantity", the verb *a pica* means to fall in small drops of liquid, and *picătură* is the result of that, a drop of liquid (*picături de ploaie*= rain drops). (But it seems that at the same time *pic* can be related to a longer [etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pic#Romanian).)

In fact, if Vulgar Latin *pitinnus* is well attested, the Wiktionary page is probably just making a confusion or a misspelling, given it doesn't mention *pitinnus* at all in this form, which means they do mention it but write it wrongly, just like the Sardinian form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why Latin, even vulgar Latin, would adopt a double-k, but that's actually beside the point.

The entry in Wiktionary has an asterisk before the word: **pitikkus*. This mark means that the word is unattested, but is reconstructed from descendant words. The idea is that because we have the Sardinian *pitticcu* and the Basque *pitika*, we likely have a vulgar Latin word that gave rise to both. However, no such recorded word exists, so the editor of that entry (or wherever they got the information from, as it, as usual, lacks a reference) marked it with an asterisk.

So no, no such word is attested.

Comment: Surely Vulgar Latin still had a length contrast in consonants?

Comment: Also, I haven't seen confirmation for Sardinian *piticcu*, it's *pithinnu* (cf. Corominas). The most important Latin reconstruction in the matter seems to be [pittus/piccus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Latin/pittus).

Comment: @Draconis - Most probably all that Wiktionary page is bad. But I read in a good dictionary (Corominas - added in my question a bit later) about a Vulgar Latin term *pitinnus* and a Sardinian *pithinnu*.

Comment: Misled by a dubious source (that quoted Corominas) I have initially said that *pitinnus* was a Medieval attested term, when in fact it's Vulgar Latin. I have corrected but I don't know yet if it's attested or reconstructed.

Comment: I read about a Sardinian *piticu* [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/432937#metadata_info_tab_contents). Anyway, if Vulgar Latin *pitinnus* is well attested, the Wiktionary page is probably just making a confusion or a misspelling, given it doesn't mention *pitinnus* at all: or rather they do mention it but write it wrongly. Which confirms your answer.

Comment: @Draconis Yes, sorry, I meant specifically using double K as opposed to double C.

Comment: @cipricus I don't know the specifics myself, I was purely referring to what's intended by the Wiktionary entry. Maybe someone else can chime in if they know more about that particular reconstruction.

Comment: *pitikkus* is not attested not because it is just reconstructed: it is not even reconstructed!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that in Sardinian piticheddu means tiny, dwarf size.

Comment: Is `piticheddu` a diminutive? Romanian has `pitic`=dwarf, but it can still get the diminutive form `piticuț` (`ț` is pronounced `ts`, like `z` in `calzone`).