# Was avē truly pronounced with an "unspelled /h/"?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, pronunciation

According to the [etymology at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ave#Latin), avē derived from a Punic word with an initial /h/, and was pronounced as such in the Classical period even though the word was spelt without.

Is this claim, that it was written avē but pronounced *havē, reliable?

Comment: What time period are you wondering about? Latin's /h/ was never especially stable and eventually disappeared completely.

Comment: I should have clarified this in the question, but the Classical period. I'm well aware that /h/ was lost — my question is about the possibility of an unspelt but pronounced /h/ (rather than a spelt but silent h-).

Comment: related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/the-latin-word-have-rather-than-ave-as-a-translation-of-the-greek-word-%ce%a7%ce%b1%e1%bf%96%cf%81%ce%b5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's what Quintilian implicitly said in his *Institutio Oratoria* (in the 1st century CE), and there's no real reason to doubt him in this case: the fact that the earliest attested plural form (in Plautus' *Poenulus*, almost three centuries earlier) is *avo* rather than *avēte* conforms to it being a Punic loan, and the Punic certainly started with *ḥ* (/ħ/ rather than /h/, but /h/ is the closest approximation Latin had). It's actually found written with the initial *h* in Latin in a number of cases, including at Pompeii, outside the House of the Faun:

[image: have]

Note that the *e* was originally short, as well: *havĕ*, not *havē*. (Though even if it were *havē* originally, it could still end up as *havĕ* due to iambic shortening.)

As for why it wasn't *always* spelled with the *h*, interference from *avē*, the 2sg. imperative of *aveō* 'I desire', is presumably to blame for that—Punic bilingualism was never widespread in Rome, so it's to be expected a folk etymology would develop. Semantically, "desire!" makes a lot less sense as a greeting than "live!", though, which is what the Punic actually meant.

Comment: Minor (!) quibble, but Quintilian did not say so in a *Declamatio minor* but rather in his [Institutionis Oratoriae Liber I (6, XXI)](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/quintilian/quintilian.institutio1.shtml#6), where he in fact reports that there are people who do *not* pronounce the h (from which we may gather that the norm would be to pronounce it). He also mentions they pronounce the last syllable long; to wit: *Multum enim litteratus qui sine adspiratione et producta secunda syllaba salutarit ("avere" est enim)* [⋯]

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel You're right, of course. I happened to have [this page](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1002/1/7/6264-6270#7) open because it was linked from the Wiktionary entry and it has the wrong title tag, was the problem.